# Passing parameters to dependent kernel module during loading

Tags: linux, module, kernel

Trying to see a way of passing parameter values to some kernel modules during startup .. the issue is 
how do i pass a parameter value to a kernel module that is getting loaded as part of modprobe of another kernel module because of the the dependency.

for eg  my requirements are 
 1.  want to pass  parameter `param1=value`  to a module `mod1`  during load time
 2. want to pass parameter `param2=value`   to  a module `mod2`  during load time

`mod1` depends on `mod2`.

we do  `modprobe  mod1  param1=value`  which  takes care of 1st requirement
 but `mod2` is getting loaded as part of  above command  hence i could not pass `param2` to it ..

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Put the module parameters in `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf` as described in the `modprobe.d(5)` man page.

```
options mod2 param2=value
```